# Service layer for an UI with multiple screens

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, model, mvp, service-layer

I am building a winforms screen. On the screen, it will show

```
Category1
  Sub-1-1
  Sub-1-2
  Sub-1-3
Category2
  Sub-2-1
```

Click on the `sub-1-1` will popup an screen and show the data related to sub-1-1; same for sub-1-2, ... etc. So there will be totally five forms (1 main form + 4 popup forms for the sample above (the actually will have about 30 sub categories)).

I have models for `Categories`, `sub-1-1`, `sub-1-2`, ..., `sub-2-1`. I am writing a service layer. Should I do,

```
public class ServiceLayer 
{
  CategoriesModel GetCategories();
  Sub11Model GetSub11();
  Sub12Model GetSub12();
  Sub13Model GetSub13();
  Sub21Model GetSub21();
  .....
}
```

Or each form has its now service class instance?

```
public class ICategoryService { ... }
public class ISubCategoryService<T> 
{
  T GetSub();
}

var sub11 = new SubService<Sub11Model>();
var sub12 = new SubService<Sub12Model>();
var sub13 = new SubService<Sub13Model>();
var sub21 = new SubService<Sub21Model>();
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one looks like a [GOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) class and will probably violate most of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. It will make the code hard to refactor, even if it's just a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

You should of course use smaller interfaces which is only handling [one responsibility](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/single-responsibility-prinicple/).